# How to use datepicker in AngularJS using custom directive as a class?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Below are my HTML and Javascript code which I used.

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="date.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app">
        <input type="text" ng-model="date" class="datepicker"></input>
        {{ date }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Java Script:**

```
var datePicker = angular.module('app', []);

datePicker.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd, MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }    
    };
});
```

Now when I click on the textbox, the datepicker popup is not coming.

Can someone please help me with a solution to make this datepicker work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see a few mistakes in your code.
You have not specifically said which datepicker you are using so I assumed it was jquery.UI based on your tags.

1) you need to add jquery.UI CSS also

2) you can't use **element.datepicker**. **element** is not jQuery object. You need to make it into jquery object. like bellow

HTML:

`<div ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="date" class="datepicker"></input>
</div>`

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.directive('datepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    require: 'ngModel',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd, MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }    
    Y};
});
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/esx6k1nc/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same format for bootstrap-datepicker. This worked for me when using bootstrap-datepicker. Add this to your controller:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    autoclose: true
 }).on('changeDate', function (date) {
    $scope.date = date.format();
    $scope.$apply();
});
```