# angular 1.5 how to create year picker dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, user-interface, jquery-ui

I am new to Angular 1 and need to implement Angular date picker to allow only year picker (graduation year) it should be from current year till 1950.

I tried using jQuery but it did not work and it seems its not compatible with Angular.

Please suggest how to implement it in Angular 1.5. The current implementation is from hard coded JSON object.

Comment: If you want to use something existing instead there are some alternatives: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this plnkr for you, hope that helps you.

Two inputs, with bootstrap.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date" id="from" placeholder="From" ng-click="app.dateFrom=true" datepicker-popup="{{app.format}}" ng-model="app.dtFrom" is-open="app.dateFrom" min-date="1970-04-06" max-date="'2017-04-06'" datepicker-options="myapp.dateOptions"
        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close">


<input type="text" class="form-control date" id="to" placeholder="To" ng-click="app.dateTo=true" datepicker-popup="{{app.format}}" ng-model="myapp.dtTo" is-open="app.dateTo" min-date="1970-04-06" max-date="'2017-04-07'" datepicker-options="app.dateOptions"
        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close">
```

And the script

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('myapp').controller('myappCtrl', function() {

  self = this;
  self.someProp = 'Calendar'
  self.opened = {};
  self.open = function($event) {

    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    self.opened = {};
    self.opened[$event.target.id] = true;

    // log this to check if its setting the log    
    console.log(self.opened);

  };

  self.format = 'dd-MM-yyyy'
});
```

Regards!!

http://plnkr.co/edit/dphcFn4ghgCQqPqRxUhi?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, Can we have only years in drop down. We dont require month and date inputs only 4 digit year in yyyy format as a dropdown.

Comment: Try this  http://plnkr.co/edit/dphcFn4ghgCQqPqRxUhi?p=preview . Only Years, no months no Day. Hope this helps you. Regards!

Comment: Thanks you are lifesaver :)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a directive as below

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.directive('datepicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    require: 'ngModel',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element).datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd, MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }    
    Y};
});
```

Taken from [How to use datepicker in AngularJS using custom directive as a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798912/how-to-use-datepicker-in-angularjs-using-custom-directive-as-a-class)